# Inser <div> into Validation Summary?

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of a native ASP.NET way to insert a `<div>` into an asp:ValidationSummary?

Comment: if you tell us what you are trying to do, perhaps we can help out

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting the div at the top you could use the Headertext attribute of the ValidationSummary like so.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="<div> Stuff inside Div </div>" />
```

**Note if you are adding the style to the actual summary section you may want to try adding your style to the  tag inside the summary.*

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to start a new block, just use a style:

```
#myDiv {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Nope the goal is to actually insert a <div> it is for styling purposes

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override the PreRender event to add this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.onprerender.aspx